# Stub an interface

Tags: java, stubbing

I have to build against an interface. To test I need to override 3 methods of an interface.
I searched for examples but wasn't able to find something that works and is well explained. I don't have a preference regarding a Mocking Framework, just suggest what suits my use case the best.

I need to stub this functionality and do not want to have 400 lines of unused overrides.

```
public class StubInventory implements Inventory
{
    private final ItemStack[] contents;

    public StubInventory (int size)
    {
         contents = new ItemStack[size];
    }

    @Override
    public void setItem (int index, ItemStack item)
    {
         contents[index] = item;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack getItem (int index)
    {
         return contents[index];
    }

    @Override
    public void clear ()
    {
        Arrays.fill(contents, null);
    }

    //<-- Insert 400 lines of unused @Override's here        

}
```

**Update:**

The getters and especially the setters are used by my code and have to work. The values are not predefined. The values will be set by my code and my test code will verify the result.

```
mockInventory = mock(Inventory.class);
//Not "nice" but will probably work
for (int i = 0; i < size * 9; i++)
    when(mockInventory.getItem(i)).thenReturn(contents[i]);
//This is where the problem is. I need to take item (ItemStack)
// and set it in my stubbed class. Basically I need to access the parameter.
for (int i = 0; i < size * 9; i++)
    when(mockInventory.setItem(i, item)).then(contents[i] = item);
```

Comment: If you have 400 lines of unused methods in your interface, your interface is probably too big. (Check out the [interface segregation principle](https://www.google.com/search?q=interface+segregation+principle).)

Comment: It's not my interface. It's an API. I cannot change the interface. I call methods from the interface and at runtime there will be an implementation available. The implementation isn't available in the test scope and I only use a small part as in the example. But at runtime I need the whole implementation of the interface.

Comment: @Diemex, this is a typical testing problem. Mock is best if you use it for unit testing. Unfortunately, your test seems to be not a unit test. Try to slice up the functionality so that you test only what your code is doing and not what the mocked interface should do. General advice I saw and heard in many forums: "a unit test should not contain for cycles". If you can modify your code to adhere to this rule, mocking will be much easier too.

Answer (score 10):

Try [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/). It is really stable and convenient for most cases. For example, you could write:

```
Inventory inventory = Mockito.mock(Inventory.class);
Mockito.when(inventory.getItem(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(somePresetItemStack);
```

You should use static import on Mockito.* methods for better readability:

```
import static org.Mockito.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). Have a look at the examples. What you want to do is a basic mocking job.